# How do I solve AttributeError: module pygame.surface has no attribute rect

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a top-down shooter in `pygame`, and I ran into this error:

```
self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
```

This is my code:

```py
from pygame import *
import pygame
from pygame import surface
from pygame.draw import rect
pygame.init()

(window_width, window_height) = (1000, 500)
window_fill_color = (255, 255, 255)
global screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('main ludum dare 49 window')
screen.fill(window_fill_color)
pygame.display.flip()
running = True


class player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((500, 250, 25, 25))
    
    def show_player(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 251), self.rect)
    
    def move(self):
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.rect_1.move_ip(0, 1)


while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.show_player(surface, screen)
    player.move()
```

Please help me. I have tried a bunch of things like adding a `get_rect`, and that stuff does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [`Classes`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). You must create an instance object of the class.

See [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

Change the name of the class to `Player`:

```py
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((500, 250, 25, 25))
    
    def show_player(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 251), self.rect)
    
    def move(self):
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.rect_1.move_ip(0, 1)
```

Create an [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)  of the `Player` class:

```py
player = Player()
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

window_width, window_height = (1000, 500)
window_fill_color = (255, 255, 255)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('main ludum dare 49 window')

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((500, 250, 25, 25))
    
    def show_player(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 251), self.rect)
    
    def move(self):
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, 1)

player = Player()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.move()

    screen.fill(window_fill_color)
    player.show_player(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```